# Convergence of series of continuous bounded functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the set of continuous bounded mappings from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Let $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ be a continuous (with respect to the $\sup$ norm) operator.

Fro given $f_0(\cdot) \in \mathcal{C}$, consider the iteration
$$ f_{k+1}(\cdot) = \frac{1}{k+1} \sum_{i=0}^{k} F[f_i(\cdot)]. $$

I am wondering under what additional conditions $f_k(\cdot) $ converges to some $\bar{f}(\cdot) \in \mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Don't seem so. Let $m=1$ and $f_0$ be the constant function $1$, and $F(f) = 2f$. Then it seems that the sequence is not bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the sum to $\sum_{i=0 }^k2^{-i} F(f_i)$ and the series should converge.

Comment: I agree. But I want to leave the iteration as it is and instead focus on assumptions on $F$. What if there exists a constant $C$ such that I restrict $\mathcal{C}$ to continuous functions uniformly bounded by $C$?

Comment: I think the restriction you need is for F to be a conttaction map

Comment: I agree, but I do not want to assume that. Unless it can be shown that $f_k$ converges to some $\bar{f}$ if and only if $F$ is a contraction map. I imagine that convergence of $f_k$ can be shown even if $F$ has more than one fixed point.